# Can a stringer be cut and joined to fit a narrow stairwell?

Tags: code-compliance, stairs, joints, load

I have a narrow unfinished basement stair with open risers. My wife would like to see the stairs "looking not like basement stairs". To do that, I'd add risers, and replace the treads with something nice. However, currently the stairs only have two stringers which span about 3' (the old treads are solid 2x something surface nailed into the stringers).

According to code, I believe a third stringer is needed for integrity, but the stairwell is long and narrow, and the landings are very shallow. I don't believe I could fit a third stringer into place. What I'd like to know is if I can actually cut the third stringer in two, affix the bottom portion to the landing pad, and then butt join the upper portion to it using a nailing plate.

I'm unsure how to calculate the load onto this new, proposed middle stringer, and whether the nailing plate will provide the strength to support people coming up and down the new stair.

Here's a rough schematic of the problematic stair and surrounding area.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Usually a landing is butted up to the stringer, so adding a new one should not be hard.  I would trust two sister pieces more than a nailing plate(my opinion only) if needed.  Pictures will help.

Comment: picture would be very useful. One thought comes to mind: put a post to support your "broken" middle stringer in the splice point

Comment: Nailing plates are absolutely, unequivocally, not a solution here. That's not at all what they do. Please provide photos to help my understand the space constraints you describe. What are the current stringers? Is the concern total load capacity, stringer bounce, tread flex, or what? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @crip659, I'm not sure what your first sentence means. Stringers usually rest _on_ a landing.

Comment: @isherwood thanks, I can upload photos later, for now, this is a rough almost-to-scale schematic of the old home. The concern, I guess, would be total load capacity. Presently, the two stringers have had no issue at all carrying the load, except as I mentioned the treads are 2x so they're very sturdy. I suppose I could replace like-for-like, although I'm concerned if 2 stringers is really meant to handle normal household traffic.

Comment: That helps. Photos of the area around the ends of the current stringers would be great. Chances are you can fit another one in between, or you can sister lumber to the two existing ones.

Comment: Can you simply refinish or re-face the treads, instead of replacing them?

Comment: @isherwood added a picture of the actual stair.

Comment: That's what I pictured, and I refurbished a nearly identical set recently. I don't see why you can't add a stringer. You can also sister 2x4 to those two or all three.